# double foreach for color shifting nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I want to draw the bottom series of circles:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[margin=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle}]
 \foreach \a in {100,90, ..., 0}{
 \foreach \n in {1,2, ..., 11}{
  \node [fill={green!\a!red}] at (\n,0)   {};
  }}

  \node [fill={green!100!red}] at (1,-2) {};
  \node [fill={green!90!red}] at (2,-2) {};
  \node [fill={green!80!red}] at (3,-2) {};
  \node [fill={green!70!red}] at (4,-2) {};
  \node [fill={green!60!red}] at (5,-2) {};
  \node [fill={green!50!red}] at (6,-2) {};
  \node [fill={green!40!red}] at (7,-2) {};
  \node [fill={green!30!red}] at (8,-2) {};
  \node [fill={green!20!red}] at (9,-2) {};
  \node [fill={green!10!red}] at (10,-2) {};
  \node [fill={green!0!red}] at (11,-2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

To avoid all the repetitions I'd like to use two `foreach` loops, but I can't seem to use them correctly, since the result is the first series of circles, with no color shifting. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your nested loops draw the first row of dots 11 times in total. At each iteration but the first one, the dots are drawn on top of those drawn during the previous iteration. Therefore, you're left with "pure red" dots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want two loops, just one:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle}]
 \foreach \n in {100,90, ..., 0}{%
    \pgfmathparse{0.1*(100-\n)+1}%
  \node [fill={green!\n!red}] at (\pgfmathresult,0)   {};
  }

  \node [fill={green!100!red}] at (1,-2) {};
  \node [fill={green!90!red}] at (2,-2) {};
  \node [fill={green!80!red}] at (3,-2) {};
  \node [fill={green!70!red}] at (4,-2) {};
  \node [fill={green!60!red}] at (5,-2) {};
  \node [fill={green!50!red}] at (6,-2) {};
  \node [fill={green!40!red}] at (7,-2) {};
  \node [fill={green!30!red}] at (8,-2) {};
  \node [fill={green!20!red}] at (9,-2) {};
  \node [fill={green!10!red}] at (10,-2) {};
  \node [fill={green!0!red}] at (11,-2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: so, to understand what's going on here, is this an alternative way or is the only way and you can't do this with two different loops?

Comment: @saras well you clearly don't want two nested loops as if you nest two loops of 11 that is 121 iterations and you only want 11 nodes.

Comment: that gold tikz badge will be yours before you know it :)